# php check wav file format?

Tags: php, if-statement, format, wav

I'm using the following code to check a wav file in php.

```
$fp=$d=$data=$format=$bit=$chn="0"; 
$fp = fopen('ppk.wav', 'r'); fseek($fp, 20); $d = fread($fp, 18);

$data = unpack('vfmt/vch/Vsr/Vdr/vbs/vbis/vext', $d);  
$format = array(0x0001 => 'PCM',0x0003 => 'IEEE Float',0x0006 => 'A-LAW',0x0007 => 'MuLAW',0xFFFE => 'Extensible',);
$bit = rtrim($data['sr'],"0") * rtrim($data['dr'],"0");  
$chn = ($data['ch'] = 1) ? "Mono" : "Stereo"; 
fclose($fp); 

echo "{$format[$data['fmt']]} {$data['sr']}Hz {$bit}bit {$chn}";    

    if ($format[$data['fmt']]!="A-LAW" || $data['ch']>1 || $data['dr']>8000 || $bit>64) {

        echo "wrong format";

    }
```

This works well and shows if the file is the wrong format.

I'd now like to check for another wav file..

So the wav file can be either A-LAW mono 8khz 64bits  OR PCM mono 16khz 512bits.

But I'm not sure how to write the if statement to check for both ?

eg:

```
if ( Alaw mon 8khz <64bit || pcm mono 16khz <512)
```

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group together the conditions describing the validity of the format and use `!` to negate it - if neither set of conditions is matched, the whole `if` condition will match:

```
if (!($format[$data['fmt']]=="A-LAW" && $data['ch']==1 && $data['dr']<=8000 && $bit<=64) &&
    !($format[$data['fmt']]=="PCM" && $data['ch']==1 && $data['dr']<=16000 && $bit<=512)) {

  echo "wrong format";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that has helped :D